# Dynamixel Control on Raspbian (ROS Groovy)

Tags: raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I have a project on which I want to control an RX-28 Dynamixel motor with a Raspberry which  has installed Raspbian with ROS groovy. The problem is that the Dynamixel packages are not yet available in the raspbian groovy repository mentioned here  /repos/rospbian/debbuild/groovy. So I think it would be possible to build the packages by myself and then use them.  I already downloaded the packages to my raspberry and put them in /opt/ros/groovy/share. but then when follow  the dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/ConnectingToDynamixelBus tutorial.
I changed the baudrate to 57142 (which I know is correct for my motor I've checked  it in windows with Roboplus). After the roslaunch I get this

File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/dynamixel_motor-master/dynamixel_controllers/nodes/controller_manager.py", line 52, in 
from dynamixel_driver.dynamixel_serial_proxy import SerialProxy
ImportError: No module named dynamixel_driver.dynamixel_serial_proxy

I know it is maybe a stupid question but I have tried everything and I still cannot communicate with the motor.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104356/dynamixel-control-on-raspbian-(ros-groovy)/) by [Mike Rasp](https://answers.ros.org/users/9111/mike-rasp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You shouldn't be manually installing things into /opt. There's a tutorial about how to setup a ROS workspace: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

The port is not yet a problem you don't yet have your environment setup such that it can find all the required source files.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0